# What's the difference between `1L` and `1`?

Tags: r, types

I often seen the symbol `1L` (or `2L`, `3L`, etc) appear in R code.  Whats the difference between `1L` and `1`?  `1==1L` evaluates to `TRUE`.   Why is `1L` used in R code?

Comment: Note: `1 == 1L` gives `TRUE`, but `identical(1, 1L)` gives `FALSE`.

Comment: See also [Clarification of L in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191324/clarification-of-l-in-r)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

So, @James and @Brian explained **what** 3L means. But **why** would you use it?

Most of the time it makes no difference - but sometimes you can use it to get your code to *run  faster* and consume *less memory*. A double ("numeric") vector uses 8 bytes per element. An integer vector uses only 4 bytes per element. For large vectors, that's less wasted memory and less to wade through for the CPU (so it's typically faster).

Mostly this applies when working with indices.
Here's an example where adding 1 to an integer vector turns it into a double vector:

```
x <- 1:100
typeof(x) # integer

y <- x+1
typeof(y) # double, twice the memory size
object.size(y) # 840 bytes (on win64) 

z <- x+1L
typeof(z) # still integer
object.size(z) # 440 bytes (on win64)
```

...but also note that working excessively with integers can be dangerous:

```
1e9L * 2L # Works fine; fast lean and mean!
1e9L * 4L # Ooops, overflow!
```

...and as @Gavin pointed out, the range for integers is roughly -2e9 to 2e9.

A caveat though is that this applies to the current R version (2.13). R might change this at some point (64-bit integers would be sweet, which could enable vectors of length > 2e9). To be safe, you should use `.Machine$integer.max` whenever you need the maximum integer value (and negate that for the minimum).

Comment: I think the memory requirements by R are the same regardless of type, at least according to `object.size`. What it is useful for is passing to Fortran or C code which may require data of a particular type.

Comment: Nope, try `object.size(1:100)` vs. `object.size(1:100+0)` it's 400 bytes + some overhead vs. 800 bytes + some overhead. I updated the example above.

Comment: Ah, yes you are right, although objects of length 1 are both 32 bytes.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the integer overflow is due to use of 32-bit signed integers, hence restricted to about +/-2*10^9, even on 64-bit R...

Comment: Why use 1L over as.integer(1)?  I guess the second statement creates a double and then converts to int?

Comment: @Zach it is also a lot shorter to type :-)

Comment: @Gavin Simpson of course.  I was really thinking of the situation where you create an entire vector, like `c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,...100L)` vs `as.integer(c(1, 2, 3, 4,...100))`.

Comment: Zach, yes it will convert, but unless you're typing in tens of thousands of values it doesn't really matter. And @Gavin: the `as.integer()` is actually shorter to type for more than 12 values :)

Comment: And of course you avoid floating point errors when storing integers as floats.

Answer (score 60):

From the [Constants Section](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Constants) of the [R Language Definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html):

> We can use the ‘L’ suffix to qualify any number with the intent of making it an explicit integer.
>   So ‘0x10L’ creates the integer value 16 from the hexadecimal representation. The constant 1e3L
>   gives 1000 as an integer rather than a numeric value and is equivalent to 1000L. (Note that the
>   ‘L’ is treated as qualifying the term 1e3 and not the 3.) If we qualify a value with ‘L’ that is
>   not an integer value, e.g. 1e-3L, we get a warning and the numeric value is created. A warning
>   is also created if there is an unnecessary decimal point in the number, e.g. 1.L.

Answer (score 51):

L specifies an integer type, rather than a double that the standard numeric class is.

```
> str(1)
 num 1
> str(1L)
 int 1
```

Answer (score 4):

To explicitly create an integer value for a constant you can call the function as.integer or more simply use "L " suffix.