# How to create a vector of integers with structure()?

Tags: r, types, integer

I don't seem to be able to produce a vector of integers using `structure()`.

```
> x <- structure(c(1,2), class='integer', mode='integer', storage.mode='integer')
> paste(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), is.integer(x))
[1] "integer numeric double FALSE"
```

Compare with a true vector of integers:

```
> y <- as.integer(c(1,2))
> paste(class(y), mode(y), storage.mode(y), is.integer(y))
[1] "integer numeric integer TRUE"
```

Any idea?

Comment: Arguments to `structure` set `attributes`, which is not how `typeof` determines the `storage.mode`. `class` is determined by an attribute, unless missing where it is given an implicit class.

Comment: I agree that this is an inconsistency in R, as the documentation for `structure`, `as.integer` , `typeof` don't really suggest the conflict presented here.  `attributes` and `mode` of an object are different.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7014387/662787 for more info on `1` vs `1L`.

Comment: ...and http://stackoverflow.com/a/8857411/662787 for more on class/mode/storage.mode etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
> x <- structure(c(1L,2L))
> is.integer(x)
[1] TRUE
```

but just

```
> x <- c(1L,2L)
> is.integer(x)
[1] TRUE
```

is ok.