# When should integers be explicitly specified?

Tags: r, integer

I often write R code where I test the length of a vector, the number of rows in a data frame, or the dimensions of a matrix, for example `if (length(myVector) == 1)`. While poking around in some base R code, I noticed that in such comparisons values are explicitly stated as integers, usually using the 'L' suffix, for example `if (nrow(data.frame) == 5L)`. Explicit integers are also sometimes used for function arguments, for example these statements from the `cor` function: `x <- matrix(x, ncol = 1L)` and `apply(u, 2L, rank, na.last = "keep")`. When should integers be explicitly specified in R? Are there any potentially negative consequences from not specifying integers?

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/7014387/602276, and see espcially the accepted answer, which answers your question very well.

Comment: @Andrie- thanks for pointing out that question and answer--don't know why it didn't come up in my initial search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `1L` etc is programmatically safe, as in it is explicit as to what is meant, and does not rely on any conversions etc.

When writing code interactively, it can be easy to notice errors and fix along the way, however if you are writing a package (even base `R`), it will be safer to be explicit.

When you are considering equality, using floating point numbers will cause precision issues [See this FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f).

Explicitly specifying integers avoids this, as `nrow` and `length`, and the index arguments to `apply` return or require integers.

Answer (score 6):

You asked:

> Are there any potentially negative consequences from not specifying
>   integers?

There are situations where it is likely to matter more.  From Chambers *Software for Data Analysis* p193:

> Integer values will be represented exactly as "double" numbers so long
>   as the absolute value of the integer is less than 2^m, the length of
>   the fractional part of the representation (2^54 for 32-bit machines).

It's not hard to see how if you calculated a value it might look like an integer but not quite be one:

```
> (seq(-.45,.45,.15)*100)[3]
[1] -15
> (seq(-.45,.45,.15)*100)[3] == -15L
[1] FALSE
```

However, it's harder to come up with an example of explicitly typing in an integer and having it come up not quite an integer in the floating point representation, until you get into the larger values Chambers describes.

Comment: Not sure why he would say, "for 32-bit machines," considering he's writing about a 64-bit double.

Comment: Don't doubles take 64-bits on 32-bit machines (e.g. two 32-bit memory locations)?

Comment: Indeed they do.  They take 64 bits on 64-bit machines too.