# Efficiently combine multiple binary/categorical columns to single categorical column in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation, binary-data, categorical-data

First of all I am aware of the related questions / answers located on the following pages.

[Convert multiple binary columns to single categorical column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227111/convert-multiple-binary-columns-to-single-categorical-column)

[For each row return the column name of the largest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735859/for-each-row-return-the-column-name-of-the-largest-value)

However my question is slightly different and these solutions above will not work for me.

Given a dataset with binary variables which may overlap, what is the most efficient way to combine them into a single categorical column?

As a simple example consider the following dataset

```
set.seed(12345)
d1<-data.frame(score=rnorm(10),
               Male=sample(c(rep(1,5), rep(0,5))), 
               White=sample(c(rep(1,5),rep(0,5))), 
               college_ed = rep(c(1,0),5))

head(d1,5)

      score   Male   White college_ed
1  0.5855288    1     0          1
2  0.7094660    1     1          0
3 -0.1093033    0     1          1
4 -0.4534972    0     1          0
5  0.6058875    1     1          1
```

The objective here is to create a new colum that will list the names of all columns equal to one.

So far this is the best solution I have come up with but I worry it is a little crude and may not be efficient if applied to a much larger data set.

```
 grp_name<-function(x){
   if(sum(x)==0){
   z<- "None"
   }else{
   z<-paste(names(x[x==1]),collapse= "-")
   }
   return(z)
   }


d1$demo<-apply(d1,1,grp_name)

     score    Male   White    college_ed        demo
1  0.5855288    1     0          1       Male-college_ed
2  0.7094660    1     1          0            Male-White
3 -0.1093033    0     1          1      White-college_ed
4 -0.4534972    0     1          0                 White
5  0.6058875    1     1          1 Male-White-college_ed
```

Anyone know of some packages for this problem or have any suggestions for speeding up the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a perfect solution but should get you on your way to something faster. The if statement doesn't vectorize but ifelse() does: see below.... no need to use the apply function.

```
set.seed(12345)
d1<-data.frame(score=rnorm(10),
               Male=sample(c(rep(1,5), rep(0,5))), 
               White=sample(c(rep(1,5),rep(0,5))), 
               college_ed = rep(c(1,0),5))

head(d1,5)

makeKey <- function(x,y,z){
  s1 <- ifelse(x == 1,"Male", "")
  s2 <- ifelse(y == 1, "White", "")
  s3 <- ifelse(z == 1, "college_ed", "")
  s4 <- paste(s1,s2,s3, sep = "-" )
  return(s4)
}

d1$key <- makeKey(x=d1$Male, y=d1$White, z=d1$college_ed)
```

Comment: Great suggestion! I realize it might have better for comparisons of processing time if I had made the example data set bigger. When I increased the size to 1 million rows your solution was around 6x faster.