# How to impute data with exclusive binary variables in R?

Tags: r, binary, missing-data, imputation, r-mice

I have a dataset with 69 columns and over 50000 rows which is structured like this:

- Some of the columns can only take 0 or 1 values (binary), for example:'isFemale', 'isChild', etc.
- Some other columns can only take 0 or 1 values (binary) but are exclusive. 
  For example, I have 3 columns called 'Primary.Language.ENGLISH', 'Primary.Language.SPANISH', 'Primary.Language.OTHER'. These columns are exclusive, so I can only have one of them True.

.

```
Primary.Language.ENGLISH    Primary.Language.SPANISH    Primary.Language.OTHER  
1                           0                           0       
0                           1                           0
```

I cannot have this (can't have more than one True in the same row)

```
Primary.Language.ENGLISH    Primary.Language.SPANISH    Primary.Language.OTHER    
1                           1                           0
```

Both types of columns have NAs (about 4-5%) and I was thinking of performing imputation with mice package in R.
However, I am afraid that, for the second type, I will have problems since imputation could not respect the constraint that I discussed above (can't have more than one '1' in the same row for each type of column of that type).
Do you have any suggestions on how I could achieve it?

Comment: Probably a way to do this in mice but a quick fix is you could construct a factor variable for the groups (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227111/convert-multiple-binary-columns-to-single-categorical-column) so that the info is encoded in one variable and then apply mice

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an in-built parameter in mice to archive this.

What you can do it to transform your variable from binary to numeric.
(e.g. a variable Primary.Language with 1 for English, 2 for Spanish, 3 OTHER)

If you use PPM (Predictive mean matching) as imputation algorithms using the **method** parameter, your constraint will be respected.

Imputations with PMM are based on values observed elsewhere. This means imputations outside the observed data range will not occur. So you won't get a 4 or 5 for the new variable as imputation.

After your imputation process you can transform back to your binary format if you need this.